When to make intention for fasting because of a promise?
Asalamualaykum,
I have been currently making up my fast and I have finished my obligatory ones but I had 3 fasts which I promised Allah سبحانه وتعالى if He (the most merciful)  made me achieve a certain something I would fast for 3 days. I am currently doing them and I didn't wake up for suhoor but made my intention at fair. I was told my fast doesn't count but I haven't eaten anything yet as I want to know if it would be invalid.And if the ruling would be the same for everyone or different.

Maybe this answer might help.

This question is similar to: Can I fast without suhoor (not during Ramadan)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you promised to fast on achieving something then this is a Nadr (vow) and is an obligatory fast - similar to a fast of Ramadan.
The view of the majority of the jurists is that the intention for an obligatory fast must be made in the night, before dawn (fajr), based on the hadith:

من لم يجمع الصيام قبل الفجر فلا صيام له
He who does not determine to fast before dawn does not fast.
— Abu Dawud

Ref:

‏ وإنما معنى هذا عند أهل العلم لا صيام لمن لم يجمع الصيام قبل طلوع الفجر في رمضان أو في قضاء رمضان أو في صيام نذر إذا لم ينوه من الليل لم يجزه
What is meant, according to the scholars, is that the fast does not count for the one who did not form the intention to fast before dawn broke in Ramadan or when making up a missed Ramadan fast or when fasting in fulfillment of a vow. If he did not form the intention to fast from the night before, then it does not count.
— Jami at-Tirmidhi translation of note from islamqa.info

